# Replace ceiling fan with basic light

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

So I removed an old ceiling fan that connected by harness, cutting the harness out, and was left with this ridiculous amount of wiring.

[image]

I’ve replaced old lights in this house with newer ones, but it was always basically just a straight swap.  I just need to get this up there and have no clue. It has two bulbs, each with one white and one black wire and a single copper for both that I assume just winds around a bare bolt in the box.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Presumably you know which wires the fan was connected to (I'd guess the read & white). So is there any reason you don't want to hook up the new lights to the same pair? Whatever you do remember to re-insulate those bare crimps again.

Comment: What is a "harness" and how did you go about "cutting it out"? ProTip™: in the future when you run into something you're not familiar with, take a _lot_ of "before" pics so you can, at a minimum, put it back the way it was.

Answer (score 1):

The two white wires from the fixture get connected to the white wires from the ceiling. I'd remove that little piece of white wire from the group with the wire nut and remove the crimp connectors on the white wires and connect them together with a wire nut. Take the two black wires from the fixture and connect them to the red wire from the ceiling. It looks like the black wires are crimped together and the connector hasn't been taped up. I'd remove that crimp connector and reconnect the black wires with a wire nut. Your bare copper wires get connected together and get fastened to the mounting bracket that your light gets attached to.

Comment: So, that’s very helpful.  It seems there are a total of 3 white wires: 2 coming from one inlet and one coming from the other.  They are then crimped all together as you said into a single that comes out of the tap as another single.  Which whites do I attach the two fixture whites to?  Are the blacks then left unused?  Both blacks from fixture attach to the single red?

Comment: @NathanCrowder  All of the white wires need to be connected together, the three in the junction box and the two from the fixture.  The black wires are your always hot: one from your source, one to another switch, room, etc., and one down to a switch with the red coming back up for your switched hot  which controls your fixture... so  both blacks from your fixture go to the single red.

Comment: @NathanCrowder none of those whites are 'spares' or optional. They all need to be connected together as they were before, and similarly both white wires from your fixture connect together to the rest of them.

Comment: Much appreciated everyone.  Working.